# How to change file name in Django pre_save?

Tags: django

Is there a way to change the file name before saving it in Django?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='foo',
        null=True,
        max_length=500)
```

At signals, I can intercept the instance during pre_save:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Foo)
def change_file_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    file_name = "TEST_" + instance.name + ".pdf"
    # save name as file name for the file field in Foo
```

I am hosting the app in the cloud so would be nice not to use saving to local machine file solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create custom function and pass it to [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```py
def custom_path(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    return f'foo/TEST_{instance.name}.pdf'

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=custom_path)
```